# Install Erlang and Elixir on MacOS M1 - Command not found

Tags: installation, erlang, elixir, apple-m1, asdf

i'm trying to install specific version of Erlang and Elixir on macos M1

I don't use brew because i can't specify version (brew installs only last version apparently)

I used ASDF with this .tool-versions files:

```
elixir 1.12.3
erlang 24.2
nodejs 16.5.0
```

but after installation, I met some errors `command are not found` when I type

```
elixir --version
iex
..
```

```
asdf plugin add erlang
asdf plugin add elixir
asdf plugin add nodejs

asdf install
```

I don't understand how to precise the path
Should I precise something in $HOME/.zshrc ?

Comment: Have you restarted your shell as specified in https://asdf-vm.com/guide/getting-started.html#_3-install-asdf ?

Comment: yes. asdf works. and i restarted my shell after elixir and erlang installations too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm including this as an answer for visibility (see Aleksei's comment):

After installing `asdf` (as with many CLI software), **you must restart your shell** (e.g. by opening a new Terminal window) or you must (re)source your profile (e.g. `source ~/.zshrc`).  This causes `asdf` to run its boot-strapping script -- e.g. `. /opt/homebrew/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh`, which establishes paths etc.

When you install `asdf` (as with lots of CLI software), pay close attention to the messages displayed in the terminal: usually there are helpful messages there that remind you to do things like this.

Comment: Thx for your answer. My solution was to integrate in zshrc .asdf/shims/

Comment: Accept the answer if it adequately solves the issue